# replace all words in a big list

Tags: python

I have a list of documents like:

```
documents = [ 'this is document number 1',
              'this is document number 2',
              'this is document number 3',
                                    ...]]
```

and a vector of around 200k words: `wordVector = ['word1', 'word2'.....'rare_word']`

where rare word is the last word in the vector. Also, corresponding to each word in the wordVector, I have a `1x2` vector (so a `Nx2` array for the complete wordVec), which are representation of these words.

Now, I want to replace all the words in "document" by their corresponding representations using `wordVector` and the `Nx2` array and if the word is not found, or the document is empty, it is assigned the last values of the `NX2` array. Right now I'm using loops and finding the word in the wordVec and then replacing them. As the dataset is huge, the process takes a  lot of time. Is there any fast/pythonic way to accomplish this?

Comment: You should update your question and include the code you are using right now.

Comment: Im using loop which goes through all the documents and another loop inside it which finds if a word exists in the "wordVector" and if it exists, it finds the corresponding value from the Nx2 array, if not it just uses the last values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a dictionary and try something like:

```
replacedWord = wordDict.get(currentWord, 'rare_word')
```

This should get you the matching replacement entry from the dictionary and will use 'rare_word' if there is no such entry.